# Validating Failed to get test status, error: Failed to get test status: INVALID(TEST_SAME_AS_APP) in Bitrise

Tags: mobile, automation, continuous-integration, appium, bitrise

I have started Appium server with the below lines of code in script step

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
npm install -g appium
appium &>/dev/null &
```

In Android Virtual Device testing step, getting the following error message. Is there any way to avoid this error

```
Validating Failed to get test status, error: Failed to get test status: INVALID(TEST_SAME_AS_APP)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Virtual Device Testing (Firebase Test Lab) feature requires two separate APKs, one that will be tested and one that will drive the test. You can read more details about the setup here: https://blog.bitrise.io/introducing-solid-and-snappy-virtual-device-testing-for-android

See the **Instrumentation** section

> For Instrumentation tests, you'll need to change your workflow:
>
> 1. Add an extra task assembleDebugAndroidTest in your gradle-runner's gradle task input, so it will be something like: `assembleDebug assembleDebugAndroidTest`.
> 2. Add Virtual Device testing for Android step after your gradle-runner step.
>      As a minimum, in Virtual Device testing for Android step set Test APK path inputs to your built debug apk (e.g.: ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk) Make sure to configure only one section of the step, which matches your desired test type!
>      (APK path is exported by the gradle-runner step, and it is set as the default for the step's input, so if you want to use a different APK then don't forget to change the step's input accordingly!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will appium works with Bitrise using The Virtual Device Testing (Firebase Test Lab)?

Comment: Unfortunately Firebase Test Lab does not support Appium.